# Create a Python entry point manually

Tags: python, python-3.x

In `setup.py` I can put something like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
  name = "my_project",
  version = "1.2.3.4",
  packages = [ "my_project" ],
  entry_points = {
    "console_scripts": [
      "my_project = my_project.__main__:main" ] } )
```

To create an entry point/executable, `my_project`, that I can call from the console.

Is it possible to create these entry points manually, in a normal Python script, outside of `setup.py`?

(I'm interested in creating these the same way `setup.py` does, so not using system-specific hashbang scripts, etc.)